# Two onClick actions one button at same time

Tags: javascript, android, button, onclick

I am developing a program in android studio. I want when I click a button then action will perform at the same time.
Function:
1st - Start count clicks
2nd - after 5 seconds that button disable

```
setDelay = new Handler();

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);

    final Button disableMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
    final  TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeUp);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void  onClick(View v){
            startDelay = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    text.setText("Time Up!");
                    disableMe.setEnabled(false);
                }
            };
            setDelay.postDelayed(startDelay, 5000);

        }
    });


    txv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tx);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mCounter ++;
            txv.setText(Integer.toString(mCounter));

        }


    });
```

Comment: What you want to achieve is everytime the Button is clicked, a counter is incremented, and after 5s of the first click it is disabled?

Comment: I appreciate your response but i am not getting it can you give me full code that i past and it work. I want one button that on click it start counting the click and after 5 seconds it decible and also show seconds count down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help

```
private int clicks = 0;


button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        final Button b = (Button)v;
        if (clicks == 0){
            // Means its the first time that a user click the button
            // Start a thread that is going to disable the button after 5 seconds from first click
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                b.setText("Time up");
                                b.setEnabled(false);
                                // Showing user clicks after button is disabled 
                                showClicks();
                            }
                         });
                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                 }
             }).start();
         }
         // Here we are just counting  . . . . including the first click
         countClicks();
    }
});
```

Count clicks method

```
private void countClicks(){
        ++clicks;
        // You can update your text view here
}
```

Showing total clicks

```
private void showClicks(){
        Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(clicks), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your response but i am not getting it can you give me full code that i past and it work. I want one button that on click it start counting the click and after 5 seconds it decible and also show seconds count down

Comment: Thank you so much sir.
can you do one little help. When i click on button it counts the click and also show counting AND also show seconds counting of disable for 5 seconds like 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: in `countClicks()` you can do something like 'textView.setText(String.valueOf(clicks))' remember to put it visible when your instantiating it

Comment: Thankyou Respected Sir, Everything is working properly I need just one little help after click on button  also SHOW THE SECOND COUNTDOWN

Comment: can you please guide me how to save high score on same activity

Answer (score 0):

create new list like this :

```
ArrayList <View.OnClickListener> clickList = new ArrayList<>();
```

then add all your Listener :

```
final Runnable startDelay;
clickList.add(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void  onClick(View v){
            if (startDelay != null)
                return;
            startDelay = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    text.setText("Time Up!");
                    disableMe.setEnabled(false);
                }
            };
            setDelay.postDelayed(startDelay, 5000);
        }
    });

clickList.add(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mCounter ++;
            txv.setText(Integer.toString(mCounter));

        }
    });
```

then , in your button add this Listener:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for (View.OnClickListener c : clickList)
                c.onClick(view);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Here multiple clicks will cause multiple `Runnables` to execute before disable, it's wrong...

Comment: solved by `if (startDelay != null) return;` , i don't know what is the point of this question, but i tried to answer on **Two onClick actions one button at same time**

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `boolean` variable to tell if the disable `Runnable` is started:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            boolean disableRunnableStarted = false;
            Runnable disableRunnable = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    //Running on UI thread to update button
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            button.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!disableRunnableStarted) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Starting disable runnable and incrementing counter...");
                    new Handler().postDelayed(disableRunnable,5000);
                    disableRunnableStarted = true;

                    //Here increment your counter
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Just incrementing counter...");
                    //Here increment your counter
                }
            }
        });
```

Replace `MainActivity` with your `Activity`'s name, if executing in a `Fragment` replace by `getActivity()`.